# Requirement of Outlook - addins

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I was trying to create an outlook add-in and saw Single sign on is required. However, `Appsource` does not allow [Single sign on add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). 
I need to know if Single sign on add-in is an requirement for an outlook add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Single sign on is not mandatory for submission to AppSource. You can check out [Authentication options in Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authentication)